# Add and Remove layers in openlayers on-the-fly

Tags: openlayers-2

I am using OpenLayers 2.13.1 in my application and I have a couple of layers which need to be added/removed to the map on-the-fly.

Here are the core codes:

```
var layers=[layer1,layer2,layer3];  // both of them are instances of ol.Layer.WMTS
var map=.....;
removeLayer();
map.events.register("moveend",map,resetLayer);  // when the center of the map changed, re-decide which layer should be visible
.....


function resetLayer(){
    var activated=[];

    var bounds=map.getExtent(),zoom=map.getZoom()
    for(var i=0,len=layers.length;i<len;i++){
        var lay=layers[i];
        if(checkVisible(bounds,zoom,layer1)){
            if(!lay.activated){
                map.addLayer(lay);   // #1
                lay.activated=true;
            }
            activated.push(lay);
        }else{
            map.removeLayer(lay);
            lay.activated=false;
        }
    }

    if(activated.length==0){
        //no layers avaiable,add the first layer
        var lay=layers[0];
            if(!lay.activated){
                map.addLayer(lay);  //#2
                lay.activated=true;
            }
    }
}
```

Now, I came to the `too much recursion` problem.

It seems that when the `moveend` event fired, the `resetLayer` will be called (expected). Once I re-add/remove the layer to the map (see comments of #1 and #2), the map object will reset the baselayer which will cause the `setCenter` to be called for the map, and the `moveend` event will be fired once again.

Any ideas on how to fix this?